# how can i add ILogger to an abstract class without adding to constructor

Tags: c#, .net, logging, ilogger

I set an instance of ILogger, but cannot use that logger without adding to constructor. If I add this to constructor I will need to set other repositories that inherits from that BaseRepository, but i want to use that logger on just the BaseRepository any ideas?

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<T, TId> : IBaseRepository<T, TId> where T : class, IBaseEntity<TId>
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly ILogger<T> _logger;

    protected BaseRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        //Can I use that _logger without adding to constructor
    }


    public virtual async Task<List<T>> FindAsync(string logId, Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
        DataPagingOptions pagingOptions = null,
        params string[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<T> queryable = _dbContext.Set<T>();

        if (includes.Any()) includes.ToList().ForEach(i => { queryable = queryable.Include(i); });

        if (filter != null) queryable = queryable.Where(filter);

        if (pagingOptions != null && (pagingOptions.PageSize.HasValue ||
                                      (pagingOptions.PageSize.GetValueOrDefault() > 0 &&
                                       pagingOptions.PageNumber.GetValueOrDefault() > 0)))
            queryable = queryable
                .Skip(pagingOptions.PageNumber.GetValueOrDefault() * pagingOptions.PageSize.GetValueOrDefault())
                .Take(pagingOptions.PageSize.GetValueOrDefault());

        //I need to show logId and a sql output
        _logger.LogInformation("LogID {}: query: {}", logId, queryable.ToQueryString());
        return await queryable.AsNoTracking().AsSplitQuery().ToListAsync();
    }
```

I tried to use LoggerFactoryExtensions

Comment: What I do in such a scenario: Create an application wide AppContext class (singleton). This AppContext holds the ILoggerFactory, from which you create Loggers everywhere in your application

Comment: @TheTanic ah yes, the "global god object" pattern, where each and every class needs a reference to your "AppContext" (as opposed to, no, in addition to, the logger).

Comment: @CodeCaster I wouldnt say god object. I use it to provide application wide helper functionalty, for example to create logger. I agree with you, thats far away from an optimal setup, but it is helpful in some occasions. Also i share your opinion, but the best way is to pass the logger variable to the class

Comment: _"application wide helper functionalty"_ - that's called a [cross-cutting concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern), and creating a singleton is one solution, but not an optimal one.

Answer (score 1):

That's just an unfortunate fact of life. Each and every class that wants access to a logger instance, must have this logger injected (or access it through some static member). This means that if you have a base class that others inherit, you must pass the logger from the derived class to its base.

You then get dependency graphs like this:

[image: dependency grapsh]

(The purple one that all other lines point to is the logger). See also:

- [Daily WTF: The Enterprise Dependency](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Enterprise-Dependency)
- [Daily WTF: Enterprise Dependency: Big Ball of Yarn](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/Enterprise-Dependency-Big-Ball-of-Yarn)

Answer (score 1):

There are only three ways your class can get an ILogger instance:

- It creates a specific ILogger itself
- It fetches the logger from some kind of shared global state (e.g. public static variable)
- The logger is injected from the outside (e.g. via the constructor)

You could also do combinations, e.g. your class creates a default logger itself, but exposes it as a settable property so you can choose a different logger in tests. Options 1 and 2 (and all combinations which include them), however, are a little naughty. Depending on the trade-offs you're willing to make and how pragmatic you need to be, it might do, but it's not the "recommended" way of doing it.

If you want to "do it by the book", inject the logger via the constructor. I hate adding loggers as ctor parameters myself, but I don't know of a better way to do it.

Comment: _"your class creates a default logger itself"_ - there is no such thing. An application can use SeriLog, console logging, log4net, and your class wouldn't know about that. Would you want a class that decides for itself where it'll log?

Comment: That's why I said it's a little naughty. I meant that for both option 1 and option 2 but I guess that wasn't clear. If logging is an afterthought, doing something naughty like opt 1 or 2 might be the pragmatic choice (to avoid adding to the big ball of yarn you mentioned). If it's to be done properly, then sure, ctor param is the way to go.